# Python Fruit Machine

Tags: python

I'm making a code for a fruit machine that selects symbols in a random manner, and cannot find out where I am going wrong. Here is the code:

```
import random

credit  = 100

def roll(credit):

    sym1 = random.choice(symbols)
    sym2 = random.choice(symbols)
    sym3 = random.choice(symbols)
    print("---Symbols---")
    print(sym1, sym2, sym3, "\n")
    if (sym1 == sym2 or sym1 == sym3 or sym2 == sym3) and not(sym1 == sym2 == sym3):
        print("Winner! +50p")
        credit += 50
        return credit

    elif (sym1 == sym2 == sym3) and sym1 != "Bell":
        print("Winner! +£1")
        credit = credit + 100
        return credit

    elif (sym1 == sym2 == sym3) and (sym1 == "Bell"):
        print("Jackpot! +£5")
        credit = credit + 500
        return credit

    elif (sym1 == sym2 == "Skull" or sym1 == sym3 == "Skull" or sym2 == sym3 == "Skull") and not(sym1 == sym2 == sym3):
        print("Two Skulls! -£1")
        credit = credit - 100
        return credit

    elif (sym1 == sym2 == sym3) and sym1 == "Skull":
        print("Three Skulls! Lose all credit")
        credit = 0
        return credit

    else:
        print("Loser!")




symbols = ["Cherry", "Bell", "Lemon", "Orange", "Star", "Skull"]
print("You have", credit, "p", "\n")


while True:
    print("")
    play = input("Roll costs 20p. Would you like to roll? yes/no: ")
    print("")
    if play == "yes" or "y" or "Yes" or "Y":
        if credit >= 20:
            roll(credit)
            credit -= 20
            print("Credit is", credit, "p")

    else:
        print("You do not have enough money to roll!")
```

The problem here is that when one wins, the credit is not added to the credit variable. The 20p is always taken away, however. I would be very appreciative of some help here.

Thanks

Comment: also `if play in {"yes","y","Yes","Y"}:` if you want to ever enter the else clause

Comment: maybe this would be better suited at **https://codereview.stackexchange.com/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also:

1. add return statement to the `else` clause in the `roll` function, otherwise the game is over after the first loss, as you'll get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'NoneType' and 'int'`.
2. Add a break statement in the `else` clause in the `while` loop - otherwise you have to stop the code manually after answering 'no'.

Full code, with suggestions from Farhan and Chris_Rands would look like:

```
def roll(credit):

    sym1 = random.choice(symbols)
    sym2 = random.choice(symbols)
    sym3 = random.choice(symbols)
    print("---Symbols---")
    print(sym1, sym2, sym3, "\n")
    if (sym1 == sym2 or sym1 == sym3 or sym2 == sym3) and not(sym1 == sym2 == sym3):
        print("Winner! +50p")
        credit += 50
        return credit

    elif (sym1 == sym2 == sym3) and sym1 != "Bell":
        print("Winner! +£1")
        credit = credit + 100
        return credit

    elif (sym1 == sym2 == sym3) and (sym1 == "Bell"):
        print("Jackpot! +£5")
        credit = credit + 500
        return credit

    elif (sym1 == sym2 == "Skull" or sym1 == sym3 == "Skull" or sym2 == sym3 == "Skull") and not(sym1 == sym2 == sym3):
        print("Two Skulls! -£1")
        credit = credit - 100
        return credit

    elif (sym1 == sym2 == sym3) and sym1 == "Skull":
        print("Three Skulls! Lose all credit")
        credit = 0
        return credit

    else:
        print("Loser!")
        return credit

symbols = ["Cherry", "Bell", "Lemon", "Orange", "Star", "Skull"]
print("You have", credit, "p", "\n")


while True:
 print("")
 play = input("Roll costs 20p. Would you like to roll? yes/no: ")
 print("")
 if play in {"yes","y","Yes","Y"}:
     if credit >= 20:
         credit = roll(credit)
         credit -= 20
         print("Credit is", credit, "p")

 else:
     print("You do not have enough money to roll!")
     break
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses all :)

Answer (score 1):

You do `roll(credit)` but don't assign the value back to credit. You need to do `credit = roll(credit)`.